# Setting regular expression to test input text which contain HTML markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create a pattern to prevent user inputs from HTML mark up. I created this patten

```
var htmlTagRegex = /^<+[a-z]+>/;
```

which only works when the input starts with html tag for example:

```
<br /> Test
<p> Test
<div> Test
```

but in case of having an input like below

```
Test <br /> 
Test <p> 
Test <div>
```

the pattern not working (probably because of `/^`). How can I write the pattern to consider any html tag contains?

Comment: yep... I'll suggest OP play with regex101.com

Comment: Hi dandavis, thanks for reply I want to detect them

Comment: then just look for an angle bracket: /</

Comment: watch out for escaped entries as well: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.*(?:<[^>]+>)).*$
```

You can use this to detect html markers.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/43

Comment: if i want to be nit-pickey, "5 < 7 || 4 > 2" still matches, as do HTML comments... but yeah, namespaced custom elements work, so this ain't bad, and likely plenty.

Comment: @dandavis, is there any way to exclude numbers from pattern?

Comment: well I update you code as `^(?=.*(?:<[^\d>]+>)).*$` and now if you put <div id="3"> it passes as can not find any match! can you please test this?

Comment: same! still passing them trough!

Comment: Thats exactly what I am saying! there is no match with html while `<div id="3">` is absolutely HTML!

Comment: what I want is filtering HTML tags

Comment: @MonaCoder with regex given which test case of yours doesn not match? use demo to try your inputs

Answer (score 0):

> now my question is can you please let me know how to power the pattern to consider any html tag contains?

```
<\w+\b[^<>]*>
```

For matching custom tags,

```
<[^<>]+>
```

To match the whole line which contains the tag. You don't need to go for lookaround assertions.

```
^.*?<[^<>]+>.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/44)

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: that doesn't match <custom-tags>

Comment: is html contains custom tags?

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information

In jQuery, If you want extract text alone without html markup , then you can use pattern like this

```
$("<div/>").html("#elementId").text()
```